# Put a long process without necessary power on pc

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberrypi

I have two pc on my home network. One of them is the Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi has static IP. I connect with it, through my another pc, with `ssh user@ip`. But if I put a long process run I have to leave my pc power on.

How can I put long or short process run on my raspberry (or another machine with Linux) and shutdown the machine with I used to connect the raspberry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through screens...

1. On the raspberry pi run the following commands to install Screen:

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install screen`
2. Once it has installed simply type:

   `screen`

   followed by  <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Now run whatever long or short process you need..
4. Now you simply have to "detach" the screen by pressing the following:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

then   <kbd>d</kbd>

Now you can disconnect from the raspberry pi and it will continue running in the background. If you want to "re-attach" to that screen, simply reconnect to the raspberry pi and type:

`screen -r`

If you need to do this again there is no need to reinstall screen so just start at step 2!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you all for your quick answer.

I install tmux and I am using now and I like that! Especially the function to create a various session ;) good that!

I will test the screen program and report about that! 
We may consider that these two programs are the same thing? Which are the difference between both?

Thanks

Comment: Screen is only one session at a time, and u can detach from it and disconnect from your computer. As far as I know you can't do that in tmux